# How to format a number from thousands to K style in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I want to change the format of y-axis from thousands to thousands in K format in plotly python.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-yaxis-tickformat)?

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation, I should use d3.format but I do not know how I should include it in python because it is JavaScript library not python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any data, or even explain what you want to show exactly on the y-axis, I will answer with what *should* work:

```py
fig.update_yaxes(tickformat=".2s")  # will format to 2 sigfigs
```

If you want regularly-spaced tick values for the y-axis, you can either pass a list of values, or use `dtick` and `tick0`, which are explained in [the documentation](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/)

So for example, you might use

```py
fig.update_yaxes(tickformat="~s", tickvals=[*range(100000, 1000000, 1000)])
```

For tick values in steps of 1000, starting at 100000, ending at 999000, trimming insignificant trailing zeros.

Note that the `K` suffix will switch to `M` once the tick values reach into the millions, and so on. If you *always* want to use `K`, you'll need to define your own using the `ticktext` parameter:

```py
tickvals = [*range(100_000, 1_000_000_000, 1000)]
ticktext = [f"{t // 1000:,}K" for t in tickvals]


fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=tickvals, ticktext=ticktext)
```

This will comma-separate and format numbers in thousands and append `'K'`, for example, `15485000` becomes `'15,485K'`.

Comment: Thank you and I added the data  but I do not know why the y-axis is like that because normally it should be with k format.

Comment: Your solution works  very well, thank you very much. fig.update_yaxes(tickformat=".2s")  and fig.update_yaxes(tickformat="~s") both work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For newcomers, **if you find your y-axis tick format is in a weird format** like mine, please make sure from the `type of the column` (`GDP` in my case). In my case, it was string because I converted a numpy array of 3 columns to dataframe and I did not pay attention to the fact that numpy array convert all values to string including GDP.